# Test for change in correlation of same two variables from T1 to T2

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

I am looking for an online calculator that will test for a significant change in correlation of the the same two variables (x and y) at 2 times, T1 (pre-study) and T2 (post-study).

I want to know the *z*-score for the change in correlation, and the related *p* value for N = 15, for the following values:

T1: Correlation of x and y = -.48

T2: Correlation of x and y = .28

Comment: Are the same subjects involved at the two times?  What can you tell us about the nature of the variables--their measurement types or their distributions or anything else that might disclose their statistical characteristics?  What do you mean by "online"?  Are you asking for Web-based software or do you want a procedure that can update the results as more data come in?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes, they are the same subjects. Variables are ordinal, measured by Likert scales. They have normal univariate distribution. Variable X: M (T1) = 5.33, SD (T1) = 0.62, M (T2) = 4.47, SD (T2) = 1.30. Variable Y:  M (T1) = 4.10, SD (T1) = 0.48, M (T2) = 4.30, SD (T2) = 0.79. Web-based software is what I was looking for but if there is a simple enough procedure to follow, I'll do my best.

Comment: If your Likert scales are really integral scales from $1$ through $7$ (or whatever), then the distributions cannot possibly be Normal!  They will be discrete--and your small SDs indicate their probabilities are concentrated at just a few values.  $N=15$ is small enough that one might be concerned that these details would raise doubts about the p-values of standard tests.

Comment: I'm using correlation analysis and t-tests and I have significant p values for both. For N=15, I have read online that both tests are appropriate for small sample sizes. So, is a sample size of N=15 too small to compare T1 and T2 correlations using a test? About normal distribution, sorry, distributions are normal as far as skewness and kurtosis are concerned; all values fell into the accepted range of -2 and +2, indicating normal univariate distribution (George & Mallery, 2010). Thank you again very much for your help.

Comment: Just because a distribution's lower moments may be close to those of another distribution does not imply they look even remotely the same.  Caution would be advisable here.

Comment: Rephrase: I am comparing T1 and T2 correlation coefficients for the correlation of a number of variables to a criterion measure at T1 and T2. One value of Pearson's _r_ changed from -.48 to .28. This seems to indicate that the relationship between the two variables changed because of the intervention, whereas the values of _r_ for correlation of other variables with the criterion measure did not change much. If the change is significant, it would indicate that this particular variable was the most affected by the intervention. How can I determine whether the change was significant? Thank you.